# JWT: 'module' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, jwt

I am getting a *Module not found error* when using [`jwt`](https://pypi.org/project/jwt/). Here is how I declared it:

```
def create_jwt_token():
    payload = {
        "iat": int(time.time())
    }

    shared_key = REST_API_TOKEN
    payload['email'] = EMAIL
    payload['password'] = PASSWORD

    jwt_string = jwt.encode(payload, shared_key)
    encoded_jwt = urllib.quote_plus(jwt_string)  # URL encode the JWT string

    return encoded_jwt
```

The error message says encode is not found in `jwt`. I did a tab on `jwt` and found that the encode is a method inside `jwt.JWT`. I tried changing it to

```
jwt_string = jwt.JWT.encode(payload, shared_key)
```

and it gives this error:

> unbound method encode() must be called with JWT instance as first argument (got dict instance instead)

What am I doing it wrong? Here is the version information of my Python environment:

> 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: You need to initialize the `JWT` object. Does `jwt.JWT().encode(...)` work?

Comment: jwt.JWT().encode(...) doesnt work. also how do i initialize the JWT object?

Answer (score 280):

The problem arises if you have both JWT and PyJWT installed. When doing `import jwt` it is importing the library JWT as opposed to PyJWT - the latter is the one you want for encoding. I did `pip uninstall JWT` and `pip uninstall PyJWT` then finally `pip install PyJWT`. After that it imported the correct module and generated the token! :)

Comment: yup, that was the case. there was a package named plain "jwt" installed by mistake which was screwing up with "PyJWT" 's JWT module.

Comment: Presently both jwt and pyjwt are reporting the same versions from `pip install`, 10.0.1. I had to come here to double check that I really wanted `pyjwt`

Comment: Make sure the flask-jwt module is also uninstalled. One more thing the pip install PyJWT=1.6.4 makes it work perfectly for me. `pip install PyJWT=1.6.4`

Comment: for me it was PyJWT version https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#jwtencode-return-type
had to dowgrade from version 2

Comment: In the past I've gotten both of these installed, and corrected it in the way described.  However today I've seen this when I didn't have JWT installed.  I needed to uninstall and re-install PyJWT.  I got rid of 2.6.0, and then installed the latest (2.8.0) and now it's working.  Would love to know why.

Answer (score 35):

I was also facing the same issue because I had named the script from which I had been calling jwt.encode() as 'jwt.py'. So be careful while naming scripts. Try not to use any library names.

Comment: very important and fixed my problem

Comment: Thats it!!! Thanks!!! Don't name your local files like library files!

Answer (score 30):

I solved this problem and @josua's answer is correct I would like to answer with details. In my case, pyJwt was already installed. I was using [getream client](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-python)

And then I was trying to install jwt using: [jwt package](https://github.com/GehirnInc/python-jwt)

And it is a known issue  [Issue Related to JWT](https://github.com/GehirnInc/python-jwt/issues/15)

So the actual problem is a quote from [Yoshida](https://github.com/yosida95):

> Unfortunately, no. As of now both libraries use the same jwt module
> namespace and Python's module system cannot resolve import jwt
> deterministically.

So I checked my pip freeze and jwt was installed and I fixed this issue by using these commands:

```
pip uninstall jwt==1.0.0
pip uninstall PyJWT
pip install PyJWT
```

And now my code:

```
encoded = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
```

works fine.

Comment: I got the following error "attributeerror module 'jwt' has no attribute 'get unverified header' ". Then i removed jwt and installed PyJWT and it started working fine.

Comment: How to implement this fix when using a requirements.txt file to install packages on a server? Without using manual commands?

Comment: On macOS Monterey, this answer was the solution. Uninstall both jwt and PyJWT first and then install PyJWT.

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I just needed to do

```
pip install pyjwt
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [PyJWT package](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/), where `jwt.encode()` works fine (no need for initialization or other kinds of stuff).

Answer (score 6):

Use [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead. I faced the same issue with [jwt](https://pypi.org/project/jwt/) so I uninstalled it and used PyJWT instead.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from (re)installing the PyJWT dependency through pip which other answers already mention make sure following files **are not** in the current directory  (i.e. `pwd`) you're either running `python` in or your `.py` script:

```
jwt.py
token.py
```

Comment: This is actually the real reason (apparently) after renaming the file name, all worked like a charm. THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
pip install djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
pip uninstall Flask-JWT && pip install Flask-JWT
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the module you are using.
You might have used **jwt** instead of **pyJWT**

```html
pip uninstall jwt
```

and install module pyJWT

```html
pip install pyJWT
```

It should work.

:) Happy Coding

Comment: If this doesn't work

Uninstall both
pip uninstall jwt 
pip uninstall PyJWT

and thn try 
pip install PyJWT

works for me

Answer (score 0):

After trying several workarounds, I created a new Python notebook with the same code and it appears to be working. I am not sure what was the issue before.

Comment: Does your notebook use a different virtual environment? The libraries may be different in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I uninstalled `jwt` and `pyjwt` and then reinstalled `pyjwt` with the latest version. However, it was not a solution for me. According to @John Hanley's answer, this worked on `MacOS`. I have `Windows 11 Home`.

After uninstalling both `jwt` and `pyjwt`, installing the `pyjwt` with a specific version worked as @Sayan Biswas mentioned.

After I run the command below, the problem was fixed.

> `pip install PyJWT==1.6.4`