# python 'jwt' module has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, jwt

This is the basic code for jwt, but it is giving me an error.

```
import jwt
en  = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
print(en)
```

*****ERROR*****

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anurag.agrawal/Desktop/HackerRank/jwt/jjwwtt.py", line 3, in <module>
    en  = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
AttributeError: module 'jwt' has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT: 'module' object has no attribute 'encode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198428/jwt-module-object-has-no-attribute-encode)

Comment: Tried uninstalling pyjwt, still it is giving the same error.

Comment: Try changing the folder name `'jwt`

Comment: And also try `jwt.JWT().encode(...)`

Comment: @RoshinRaphel, changed the folder name, it is still the same.

Comment: @RoshinRaphel, used jwt.JWT().encode(....) now the error is -

encodee = jwt.JWT().encode({'some': 'payload'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'jwt' has no attribute 'JWT' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: For @RoshinRaphel suggestion to work on my side, I had to switch from Pipenv and move to Venv and do the installations. Perhaps Pipenv was installing / managing an older installation of PyJWT (for me).

Answer (score 2):

On going through various articles over the internet, finally got the solution to this problem, the library imported is to be pyjwt, as below:

---

from jwt import PyJWT

en = PyJWT.encode({'some' : 'payload'}, key= 'secret' , algorithm= 'RS256')
print(en)

---

*There are a few errors I am getting post this, but for now, the problem of library is resolved.*